How to set a default field selected using react-native-element-dropdown
Here's my dropdown using react-native-element-dropdown library. It's working fine, but I'd like to be able to select one of the elements by default when a page renders. Instead of showing a placeholder, it shows a selected category.
  <Dropdown
            style={styles.dropdown}
            placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
            selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
            inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
            iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
            data={categoriesData}
            search
            maxHeight={300}
            labelField="name"
            valueField="id"
            placeholder="Select or create a category"
            searchPlaceholder="Start typing to search..."
            containerStyle={{ borderRadius: 8 }}
            value={categoryId}
            onChange={(category) => {
              setCategoryId(category.id);
            }}
          />


Use the initial value in useState. In the example below the first item is set as default.
const DropdownComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(data[0]);

  return (
    <View style={{ padding: 16 }}>
      <Dropdown
        data={data}
        labelField="label"
        valueField="value"
        placeholder={'Select item'}
        value={value}
        onChange={(item) => {
          setValue(item.value);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const data = [
  { label: 'Item 1', value: '1' },
  { label: 'Item 2', value: '2' },
  { label: 'Item 3', value: '3' },
  { label: 'Item 4', value: '4' },
  { label: 'Item 5', value: '5' },
  { label: 'Item 6', value: '6' },
  { label: 'Item 7', value: '7' },
  { label: 'Item 8', value: '8' },
];

